# A hopeless optimist - who am I?

Tags: riddle

I can be a hopeless optimist, or crookedly straight
My three beginnings are half of an eight
The rest of me works hard as a fool
I may be pretty ugly, but also nerdishly cool

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are an

> Oxymoron

I can be a hopeless optimist, or crookedly straight

> 'Hopeless optimist' and 'crookedly straight' are oxymorons - phrases with terms that contradict each other.

My three beginnings are half of an eight

> **oxy** is half of oxygen, the element with atomic number 8. Also, three is not half of eight, making the statement itself a sort of oxymoron

The rest of me works hard as a fool

> **moron** is another word for fool; "rest" also has another meaning that is incongruous with "hard work"

I may be pretty ugly, but also nerdishly cool

> 'pretty ugly' and 'nerdishly cool' are two more oxymorons (though, in this case, 'pretty' could be read as being used as an adverb, not an adjective, which would be a true oxymoron)

Comment: @gamow lol, thank you - I don't know what happened that resulted in me not getting that part

Comment: Nice. Also: "the rest of me works hard"...

Comment: @BigBlackBox Oh, I didn't know that was also supposed to be solved. I'm having a hard time coming up with anything there at the moment.

Comment: It's not a big clue to be solved, just: rest != hard work, so another small example.

Comment: Anyway nice work for solving it so fast. Have you considered changing your name to question_answerer?

Comment: @BigBlackBox I dunno, there's probably a lot of paperwork involved.

Comment: Also, Oxes work hard.  Ox + moron = Hard working fool.

Comment: But 3 *is* half of 8: the right half if you cut it vertically

Comment: @quintopia well look at mr lateral thinking over here